# Google Analytics & this.selectedIndex : Information don't comes up

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to track a `onChange` action on a select list.
I need to return a selectedIndex, seams not working.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="triOrdre" id="triOrdre" 
    onchange="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Outils','Trier',this.selectedIndex]);">
    <option value="myURL0">Option0</option>
    <option value="myURL1">Option1</option>
    <option value="myURL2">Option2</option>
    <option value="myURL3">Option3</option>                  
    <option value="myURL4">Option4</option>
</select>
```

The information I need is 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4, regarding to the selectedIndex.
If I put `this.value`, I get the selectedValue (so myURL0, 2, ...).
But nothing is working with selectedIndex.

BUT:
If I try on Chrome with the GA debug pluggin, the pluggin see the trackevent with the expected values.
Ex: `['_trackEvent','Outils','Trier',1]`
but nothing appear in firebug or HTTPFox pluggin.

Thanks reading,
and thanks for you future help.

Jim.

Comment: Is that your real code? You are missing the opening quote on `Outils'`. You ought to be seeing console errors about that...

Comment: No it's not. There is no missing quotes in my real code. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I got the answer.

`this.selectedIndex` is an Integer, and the GA API seams expect only sting values.

So I need to convert the Int value into String like that:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Outils','Trier',this.selectedIndex.toString()]);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers handle script/html syntax errors differently.  As Michael suggested in your comments, try closing your single quote appropriately on your Event Category.

```
onchange="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outils', 'Trier', this.selectedIndex]);"
```

Fixing this will help you find any other problems if they exist as you will get more consistent debugger results.

**UPDATE**

It could be how your `onchange` event is handling `this.selectedIndex`.  You could try putting that code in a separate function and using `console.debug(this.selectedIndex)` to make sure its getting the expected value.

```
onchange="trackEvent(this)"
```

Then...

```
function trackEvent(selectBox) {

 var selectIndex = selectBox.selectedIndex;
 console.debug(selectIndex);

 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outils', 'Trier', selectIndex ]);

}
```

This may help you debug the problem. One other thing that may help is to ensure that if the selected index is the GA `Value` you are trying to track, make sure its an integer and not a string.

Comment: Sorry, there is no missing quote in the real code. It's a copy/past error while writing the question.

Comment: `this.selectedIndex` where giving the correct value. It was not the issue. Check my answer for more details. But thanks for your help.